# Проблема с браузерной строкой Денвера или...

Tags: php, denwer

При попытке прописать это в Денвере в строке браузера http://http/Z:/home/localhost/mysite.loc/www/ автоматически прописывает file? то есть вместо http пишет file и соответственно не начинается установка Джумла. Используется гугл хром и виндоус хп.

Answer (score 1):

Все правильно.

Comment: Как же начать установку Джумла в чем ошибка

Comment: В данном случае Google пишет что не может найти страничку, как быть?

Answer (score 1):

Если Joomla находится в `Z:/home/localhost/mysite.loc/www/` то открывать надо `http://mysite.loc/`

[Работа с виртуальными хостами в Денвере](http://www.denwer.ru/base.html)

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте пройти по следующим ссылкам

http://localhost или http://localhost/www

я не знаю, какова верная иерархия именно в вашем случае. в общем, вам необходимо ваш сайт найти на `localhost` или на `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Для установки Джумла на Денвер требует для начала установки программы ввести в строке браузера путь, после чего автоматически начнется установка Джумла, но у меня автоматически вместо http прописывает File и никакой установки не начинается а просто появляются папки дистрибутива Джумла. Как же начать установку программы? Почему гугл не находит http?

Comment: http://localhost этот адрес работает, Денвер запускает, базы данных создала, тестирование полностью работает Денвера. Вопрос стоит в том, чтобы начать установку Джумла